# Creating Column conditional formatting that are only visible in specific views

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, list-view, modern-experience, json-formatting

My department has a list that are used by many teams. For team's views I would like to format columns that will note affect the view of the other teams.

It looks like by default, column conditional formatting affect all views. Is there away to accomplish this?

Example: This is code works but I would like it to only affect one specific view.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "@currentField",
  "style": {
    "background-color": "=if(([$TargetDate]>=@now && [$TargetDate]<(@now +864000000)), '#b6d7a8', if([$TargetDate]<=@now, '#ea9999', '#ffffff'))",
    "color": "black",
    "font-size": "1em",
    "justify-content": "center"
  }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Column JSON formatting is applied at the column settings level and it cannot be controlled at list view level.

---

If you want to highlight the row based on column values, you can use view formatting (`additionalRowClass`).

Check this documentation: [Use view formatting to customize SharePoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/view-formatting)

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible using a single field. Column formatting applies to the field (list or site column level) and is utilized in every view (unless completely overridden with a rowFormatter).

However, you can create a calculated column that simply equals the value of the other column. You can apply the format to either column (depending on the form experience you want it may make more sense to apply it to the calculated column and remove it from the form). By having 2 columns that have the same values (but you only have to enter it in one spot) you can choose which column has a format and which view(s) they are each a part of.